# plotly plots keep disappearing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plotly

Made a function to use plotly to plot multiple line plot. In this case, the code will plot all the product time series for each city.
While used the function again the previous plots just disappeared.
Tried to make notebook 'trusted'
Also include

```
import kaleido
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

def plot_city_products(sales,cities,products):
    c_list = sales[cities].unique()
    for c in c_list:
        print(c)
        cc = sales[sales[cities]==c]
        reshaped = cc.pivot(index='week', columns=products, values='values')
        cols = sales[products].unique()
        tt = reshaped.reset_index()      
        fig = px.line(tt, x="week", y=cols)
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename="{}.html".format(c))
        fig.show()
```

but these do not solve the problems.

If run `plot_city_products(sales,cities,products)` multiple times, previous plots keep disappearing.
Just wonder if there is other ways I could give it a try?

The plots just look this, blank plots with an unhappy face.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `pio.renderers.default` to 'jupyterlab' ?

Comment: yes. see my post.

Comment: Have you tried `import plotly` followed by `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`

Comment: If the line @JacobK suggests doesn't work, could you also post the code for the line plot? Are you running `fig.show()` or using pio?

Comment: Yes. I used fig.show() in my code. is the line bring the trouble?

Comment: @DerekO, just added the code.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? That unhappy face might indicate that the [rendering process crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60385538/plotly-displaying-sad-fail-face-instead-of-output). What happens if you restart the browser or try a different one?

Comment: Can you look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334026/16733101